# Mobile Detection or screen size

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, device, browser-detection

I am want to start using jQuery mobile for some of my sites, previously i have been using media queries to detect the screen size and deliver css based on screen size however some of my clients would do better with a mobile version of the site, meaning redirect to mobile.website.com, rather than using css, this would allow me to develop better with jQuery mboile in some cases.
My question is what is the best way to do it, do you have to detect the useragent or just screen size.
and if so what is the best way to do this, I have read numerous ways of doing this but there doesnt seem to be any kind of standard. In the past i used a script to detect mobile device and the Safari browser on a desktop mac picked it up also, my knowledge in this are isnt great so i would be greatful for any artilcles or knowledge worth reading.

I have noticed Android browser tends to pick up 768 and below where iphone picks up 480 and below and at times i find i have 4 different style sheets, where if i could detect if mobile device redirect to url. A one version for all mobile devices type of solution

Is it better to stick with responsive design and CSS.
thanks in advance for any comments

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a site which supports only mobile devices, better use jQuery Mobile. If you want the site to work both on mobile devices and desktops, this isnt a good option.

jQuery Mobile uses more of a fluid layout which makes sure that your website renders well on different screen sizes. Where as resposive design is useful when you need to hide/display information based on the screen sizes.

Since the requirement is focussed more on detecting the screen sizes rather than detecting the browser, it's better to go with the responsive design with the use of media queries to support mobile devices and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET MVC? in that case all you have to do for a mobile view to show instead of a web view is to copy your regular views and append .Mobile to them so lets say your regular page is index.cshtml - to make a mobile version all you have to do is to copy it and name is index.mobile.cshtml and MVC takes care of it for you..

Tutorial - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

Now if you are NOT using MVC but are just doing a basic html/javascript website then you basically need to rely on the css media tags and create different mark up based on that.

Twitter bootstrap is another alternative to doing this as they have an almost out of the box responsive design in their CSS

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/